Bug in MathJax with latex when one uses $V^{{swap}}_{T_s}$
I have just encountered the following Mathjax bug while trying to write a question :

It is not related to the use of \textrm as one can see with :

Remark : I tried on math.stackexchange.com by curiosity and the bug does not happen there.

It is not a bug in MathJax, it is a bug in the new StackExchange editor that allows interactions between Markdown and LaTeX notation to occur.  In this case, it is the underscores, which Markdown uses to form italics.  Note that the {T_s} is in italics in the preview, as is the V^{{swap}} in the final expression.  That is because the first underscore in the first expression is being matched with the first underscore in the last expression, and the editor is inserting <em> for the first and </em> for the second.  That puts the end of the first expression through the beginning of the last expression into <em>...</em>.  Since MathJax doesn't process math that contains HTML tags (the math must be purely text), that <em> tag prevents the first or last expressions from being processed.
Moreover, the content now is <em>{T_s}$ the value at a future date $T_s$ ... is equal to $V^{{swap}}</em>, so MathJax finds the first two dollar signs here as the math delimiters, and so typeset the text in between.  That is why you see "the value at a future date" in math italics.  Similarly for the other text inside the <em>.
It used to be that the editor properly protected the mathematics notation from being processed by Markdown, but a recent update to the editor seems to have broken that.  My understanding is that the back-end will still process things correctly when you submit your post, but the preview will be broken.  That is an unfortunate inconsistency.
You can use \_ instead of _ to avoid the problem in the preview, but then it will no longer show properly in the final post.  You might be able to uses spaces before or after the _ to avoid Markdown's italics, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for your answer ! This fails to explain why it does not happen in math.stackexchange.com though, as I guess it uses the same editor as quant.stackexchange.com and does not have the same issue ? Or am I missing something  ?

I think they are still rolling out the new preview editor, and some site have it while other haven't been changed over yet.  Or it might be user-based, as I see the old editor here, whereas your image is of the new one, I think.

Also, did you do the exact same expressions in math SE?  It requires two expressions with appropriate underscores in them.  I just checked in math SE myself, and it did the same thing as your image here for me.

I did the same comparison, unless it would not be a comparison.
